# Excel If Yes AND Yes

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I have 2 columns of yes/no answers
I want to count if yes and yes, how many is that

I tried using =countif(G2:G256, "yes")AND(H2:H256, "yes)) but that doesn't work.

Any help? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You want COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS(G2:G256, "yes",H2:H256, "yes")
```

Comment: THANK YOU! OMG it was taking me forever... -_- I'm not an excel person lol